# Where does the argument in w.erase(unique_copy(v.begin(),v.end(),w.begin())); points to?

Tags: c++

I'm learning c++ for an university course, and I have a question but i am not sure how to word it so there may be a similar question to this one somewhere but I couldn't find it. If this post happen to be a duplicate, please do redirect me ! Also english isn't my first language, pardon my french.

So about my question :

- context : we have practice questions to do before our exam

We are given this code :

```
vector<int> v{1,1,2,2,2,3,4,4,3,3,2}; 
vector<int> w(8);

w.erase(unique_copy(v.begin(),v.end(),w.begin()));

for (int e: w) cout << e << ' ';
```

I thought the argument in w.erase(x) was supposed to remove a single element from the position x or a range of element.

But I don't understand which position "unique_copy(v.begin(),v.end(),w.begin())" would point to ? (again sorry for if the terms I use aren't correct)

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Did you look [at the reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique_copy)? And it seems the code is broken, it lacks `, w.end()` as the second argument for `.erase()` to do the right thing.

Comment: @holyblackcat I did look at the reference and I know what would the result of unique_copy be, but I don't know what it does when it's in w.erase() - I also looked the reference of std::vector::erase() but didn't find an explanation that I understood.

Comment: Hopefully the second half of my comment should make it more clear. They intended to call the two-argument version of `.erase()` that takes two iterators, but forgot the second argument.

Comment: @holyblackcat, yes thank you ! Now it makes more sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a number of issues in the code but first to answer your question, if we add a temporary variable it's easier to explain:

```
auto end = unique_copy(v.begin(),v.end(),w.begin());
w.erase(end);
```

[`std::unique_copy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique_copy) returns an iterator to one after the last element written in `w` by `unique_copy`. `w.erase(end)` then removes just that element. What you actually want to do is erase all elements from `end` onwards. The correct code would be `w.erase(end, w.end())`.

There is still an issue that `std::unique_copy` might try to write more elements than fit inside `w`. In this particular case `w` happens to be big enough but to be safer (and to avoid having to call `erase`) it's better to use [`std::back_inserter`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter):

```
std::vector<int> v{1,1,2,2,2,3,4,4,3,3,2}; 
std::vector<int> w;

std::unique_copy(v.begin(),v.end(),std::back_inserter(w));
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! Indeed, using a temporary variable made it more clear to me. also, thank you for pointing out the issues - I didn't notice them.